# Swift 4 When button is pressed a second time following an error alert it doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift4

I'm sure the answer to my question is very simple but I can't seem to find the answer online. I'm probably not wording it well.

I'm creating an app that's for data collection and won't be public, therefore I'm using Core Data to manage users. There won't be more than a few users using each device.

When the user tries to create a new email using an email that already exists an alert comes up as I want. However, when they exit the alert and try entering an email again the button doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
  @IBAction func startSessionButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    // check email isn't already in use
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(request)

        if results.count > 0 {
            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
                let email = result.value(forKey: "email") as? String
                if email == inputField.text {
                    newUser = false
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Email already in use!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
                    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    if newUser {
        let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Users", into: context)
        newUser.setValue(inputField.text, forKey: "email")
        newUser.setValue(1, forKey: "session")
        newUser.setValue(0, forKey: "phraseNumber")
        newUser.setValue(UIDevice.current.modelName, forKey: "device")

        emails.append(inputField.text!)
        sessions.append(1)
        phraseNumbers.append(0)

        myIndex = emails.index(of: inputField.text!)!

        do {
            try context.save()
            print("saved")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

How do I 'reset' the button so that when the user tries a 2nd or 3rd time it responds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your button click if you write email that is already exist then `newUser` is set with `false`, so you need to reset `newUser` with `true` before making fetch request.

```
@IBAction func startSessionButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    //Set newUser to true
    newUser = true
    // Now check email isn't already in use
    ...
}
```

**Suggestion :-** You need to use `NSPredicate` with your `NSFetchRequest` instead of fetching all users.

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "email == %@", inputField.text ?? "")
//Now just check that array is empty or not.
do {
   let results = try context.fetch(request)
   newUser = results.isEmpty
}
//Note:- If you check like this then there is no need to reset newUser variable
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I knew it would be something simple. And yes I'll look into using NSPredicate instead. First time looking at this.

Comment: @Hardy143 Welcome mate :)